# Generating similar named entities/compound nouns

Tags: spacy

I have been trying to create distractors (false answers) for multiple choice questions. Using word vectors, I was able to get decent results for single-word nouns.

When dealing with compound nouns (such as "car park" or "Donald Trump"), my best attempt was to compute similar words for each part of the compound and combine them. The results are very entertaining:

- Car park -> vehicle campground | automobile zoo
- Fire engine -> flame horsepower | fired motor
- Donald Trump -> Richard Jeopardy | Jeffrey Gamble
- Barrack Obama -> Obamas McCain | Auschwitz Clinton

Unfortunately, these are not very convincing. Especially in case of named entities, I want to produce other named entities, which appear in similar contexts; e.g:

- Fire engine -> Fire truck | Fireman
- Donald Trump -> Barrack Obama | Hillary Clinton
- Niagara Falls -> American Falls | Horseshoe Falls

Does anyone have any suggestions of how this could be achieved? Is there are a way to generate similar named entities/noun chunks?

---

I managed to get some good distractors by searching for the named entities on Wikipedia, then extracting entities which are similar from the summary. Though I'd prefer to find a solution using just spacy.

Comment: Interesting (+1 on auto zoo ).  Can you edit and post the original question text?  I'd like to see what the question is where "car park" or "donald trump" etc. is the answer.  (Asking because using key words from the question may be helpful.)

Comment: There were no actual questions. I just used the examples of answers which are similar to what I expect the answers are going to be. The question could be "Who is the 45th president of USA?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't seen it yet, you might want to check out [`sense2vec`](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec), which allows learning context-sensitive vectors by including the part-of-speech tags or entity labels. Quick usage example of the spaCy extension:

```py
s2v = Sense2VecComponent('/path/to/reddit_vectors-1.1.0')
nlp.add_pipe(s2v)
doc = nlp(u"A sentence about natural language processing.")
most_similar = doc[3]._.s2v_most_similar(3)
# [(('natural language processing', 'NOUN'), 1.0),
#  (('machine learning', 'NOUN'), 0.8986966609954834),
#  (('computer vision', 'NOUN'), 0.8636297583580017)]
```

[See here](https://explosion.ai/demos/sense2vec) for the interactive demo using a sense2vec model trained on Reddit comments. Using this model, ["car park"](https://explosion.ai/demos/sense2vec?word=car%20park&sense=auto) returns things like "parking lot" and "parking garage", and ["Donald Trump"](https://explosion.ai/demos/sense2vec?word=Donald%20Trump&sense=auto) gives you "Sarah Palin", "Mitt Romney" and "Barack Obama". For ambiguous entities, you can also include the entity label – for example, ["Niagara Falls|GPE"](https://explosion.ai/demos/sense2vec?word=Niagara%20Falls&sense=GPE) will show similar terms to the geopolitical entitiy (`GPE`), e.g. the city as opposed to the actual waterfalls. The results obviously depend on what was present in the data, so for even more specific similarities, you could also experiment with training your own sense2vec vectors.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. It does pretty much what I needed